# Vue(tify) Transition- children must be keyed - yet there are not even any tags as children

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to use a transition on a list on vuetify or vue and yet I keep getting the error `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: <transition-group> children must be keyed: <v-card>`

I tried the vuetify way

```
<v-fade-transition group tag="v-card">
     <v-card v-for="(item, index) in usersData" :key="item.email" class="pa-5 my-7">         
 {{item}}, {{index}}
     </v-card>
</v-fade-transition>
```

as well as the vue way:

```
<transition-group name="list" tag="v-card">
         <v-card v-for="(item, index) in usersData" :key="item.email" class="pa-5 my-7">         
            {{item}}, {{index}}         
</v-card>
</transition-group>
```

and still get the error. So I wonder what exactly should I key?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like following snippet, read more [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/transitions/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      usersData: [{email: 'aa@a.com'}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addCard() {
      this.usersData.push({email: 'dd@a.com'})
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-btn elevation="2" @click="addCard">add</v-btn>
        <transition-group name="scale-transition" tag="v-card" appear>
          <v-card v-for="(item, index) in usersData" :key="index" class="pa-5 my-7">         
          {{item}}, {{index}}
          </v-card>
        </transition-group>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Inserted that into my component and saw it working. Thus no issue with setup or vue. Then later figured out i was referenced my datastructure element wrongly and item.email didn't exist but item.user.email. That solved it.